# Calendar Reminder not working in custom calendar account

Tags: android, events, calendar, reminders

I have implemented custom calendar account for one of app, got stuck at calling reminders of events. I have following questions -

1. during calendar account creation, I am using

   ```
   values.put(Calendars.VISIBLE,0);//tried with 1
   values.put(Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS, 1);
   values.put(Calendars.CAN_PARTIALLY_UPDATE, 
   values.put(Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL,Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_ROOT)
   ;// also tried Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_OWNER
   ```

   So my question is:

   i) when calendars.VISIBLE is 0, still account become visible in splanner calendar app which is default in samsung devices.

   ii) I didn't find any difference b/w calendar access level, can any one clear this?
2. reminder for events are not working. when inserting reminder, i get correct uri after inserting reminder but that reminder is not getting called. But when I add this account in sPlanner and sync all events then reminders start working which is not required.